# using V-ing after When

Tags: grammar, present-participles, participle-clauses, time-reference

Actually I'm doing a Grammar exercise that require me to identify mistake in a sentence. Here's the sentence:

> (A)**When** hearing the weather forecast, we decide (B)**not** to go camping (C)**in** the (D) **mountains**.

The correct answer is A (when)
It should be corrected to **On** hearing.

Could you explain the answer for me? I think V-ing is correct too...

Answer (score -2):

> When hearing the weather forecast, we **decided** not to go camping.

Comment: There's now way it is "we decided not to go for camping"; it's "we decided not to go camping."